# How to connect a user using the OpenVPNAdapter

Tags: ios, swift, openvpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I am working on a personal project where I will be connecting the user to a VPN. I have followed two blog posts on doing this which are https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-build-an-openvpn-client-on-ios-c8f927c11e80 & https://kean.blog/post/vpn-configuration-manager. I was able to configure the VPN settings but still, it does not connect. Here are the images for my project Signing & Capabilities one for the App and the other is for the network extension.

[image] [image]

my ViewController looks like this. There is a folder in the user app document directory that is named **user** which gets downloaded from the internet and these are the files that are in the folder. I am not sure if I am supposed to use it other than the user.ovpn file

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Zip
import Alamofire
import NetworkExtension

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedServer: Server?
    
    var providerManager: NETunnelProviderManager!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.loadProviderManager {
            self.configureVPN(serverAddress: "openvpn://\(self.selectedServer!.server.address):\(self.selectedServer!.server.port)", username: "\(self.username)", password: "\(self.password)")
        }
    }
    
    func loadProviderManager(completion:@escaping () -> Void) {
        NETunnelProviderManager.loadAllFromPreferences { (managers, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.providerManager = managers?.first ?? NETunnelProviderManager()
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func configureVPN(serverAddress: String, username: String, password: String) {
        guard let configData = self.readFile(path: "user/user.ovpn") else { return }
        self.providerManager?.loadFromPreferences { error in
            if error == nil {
                let tunnelProtocol = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
                tunnelProtocol.username = username
                tunnelProtocol.serverAddress = serverAddress
                tunnelProtocol.providerBundleIdentifier = "com.example.Networking.tunnel"
                tunnelProtocol.providerConfiguration = ["ovpn": configData, "username": username, "password": password]
                tunnelProtocol.disconnectOnSleep = false
                self.providerManager.protocolConfiguration = tunnelProtocol
                self.providerManager.localizedDescription = "OpenVPN"
                self.providerManager.isEnabled = true
                self.providerManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                    if error == nil  {
                        self.providerManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) in
                            do {
                                try self.providerManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                            } catch let error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    func readFile(path: String) -> Data? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(path)
            return try Data(contentsOf: fileURL, options: .uncached)
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

And my PacketTunnelProvider looks like this

```
import NetworkExtension
import OpenVPNAdapter

class PacketTunnelProvider: NEPacketTunnelProvider {
    
    var startHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)?
    var stopHandler: (() -> Void)?
    var vpnReachability = OpenVPNReachability()
    
    var configuration: OpenVPNConfiguration!
    var properties: OpenVPNProperties!
    var UDPSession: NWUDPSession!
    var TCPConnection: NWTCPConnection!
    
    lazy var vpnAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter = {
        let adapter = OpenVPNAdapter()
        adapter.delegate = self
        return adapter
    }()
    
    override func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        guard
            let protocolConfiguration = protocolConfiguration as? NETunnelProviderProtocol,
            let providerConfiguration = protocolConfiguration.providerConfiguration
            else {
                fatalError()
        }
        guard let ovpnFileContent: Data = providerConfiguration["ovpn"] as? Data else { return }
        let configuration = OpenVPNConfiguration()
        configuration.fileContent = ovpnFileContent
        do {
            properties = try vpnAdapter.apply(configuration: configuration)
        } catch {
            completionHandler(error)
            return
        }
        configuration.tunPersist = true
        
        if !properties.autologin {
            if let username: String = providerConfiguration["username"] as? String, let password: String = providerConfiguration["password"] as? String {
                let credentials = OpenVPNCredentials()
                credentials.username = username
                credentials.password = password
                do {
                    try vpnAdapter.provide(credentials: credentials)
                } catch {
                    completionHandler(error)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        
        vpnReachability.startTracking { [weak self] status in
            guard status != .notReachable else { return }
            self?.vpnAdapter.reconnect(afterTimeInterval: 5)
        }
        
        startHandler = completionHandler
        vpnAdapter.connect()
        
    }
    
    override func stopTunnel(with reason: NEProviderStopReason, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        stopHandler = completionHandler
        if vpnReachability.isTracking {
            vpnReachability.stopTracking()
        }
        vpnAdapter.disconnect()
    }
    
    override func handleAppMessage(_ messageData: Data, completionHandler: ((Data?) -> Void)?) {
        if let handler = completionHandler {
            handler(messageData)
        }
    }
    
    override func sleep(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    override func wake() {
    }
    
}

extension PacketTunnelProvider: OpenVPNAdapterDelegate {
    
    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, configureTunnelWithNetworkSettings networkSettings: NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings?, completionHandler: @escaping (OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow?) -> Void) {
        setTunnelNetworkSettings(networkSettings) { (error) in
            completionHandler(error == nil ? self.packetFlow : nil)
        }
    }
    
    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleEvent event: OpenVPNAdapterEvent, message: String?) {
        switch event {
        case .connected:
            if reasserting {
                reasserting = false
            }
            guard let startHandler = startHandler else { return }
            startHandler(nil)
            self.startHandler = nil
        case .disconnected:
            guard let stopHandler = stopHandler else { return }
            if vpnReachability.isTracking {
                vpnReachability.stopTracking()
            }
            stopHandler()
            self.stopHandler = nil
        case .reconnecting:
            reasserting = true
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleError error: Error) {
        guard let fatal = (error as NSError).userInfo[OpenVPNAdapterErrorFatalKey] as? Bool, fatal == true else {
            return
        }
        NSLog("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        NSLog("Connection Info: \(vpnAdapter.connectionInformation.debugDescription)")
        if vpnReachability.isTracking {
            vpnReachability.stopTracking()
        }
        
        if let startHandler = startHandler {
            startHandler(error)
            self.startHandler = nil
        } else {
            cancelTunnelWithError(error)
        }
    }
    
    func openVPNAdapter(_ openVPNAdapter: OpenVPNAdapter, handleLogMessage logMessage: String) {
        NSLog("Log: \(logMessage)")
    }
    
}

extension PacketTunnelProvider: OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow {
    
    func readPackets(completionHandler: @escaping ([Data], [NSNumber]) -> Void) {
        packetFlow.readPackets(completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
    
    func writePackets(_ packets: [Data], withProtocols protocols: [NSNumber]) -> Bool {
        return packetFlow.writePackets(packets, withProtocols: protocols)
    }
    
}

extension NEPacketTunnelFlow: OpenVPNAdapterPacketFlow {}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you resolve it yet?

Comment: No, I just gave up on this project.

Comment: I just change to another VPN Server and code works now. Did you try?

Comment: Really, that's strange. I was doing this app a while go trying to push it to the App Store for free. But I have delete that project from my computer. DM me on twitter if you can https://twitter.com/mutaebalqahtani

Comment: hello. you get success on that?

Comment: I'm following same tutorial and had same issue, (Update Required!), any points I should check?